# I moved a running project from one pc to another, now it provides database related errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I have a project which was running perfectly in my old PC locally in Visual Studio, due to some reasons i had to change my computer and had to move the project into the new pc but now it is generating an error as follows in the local machine.

```
Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Shoaib\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FEFA_MIS\FEFA_MIS\App_Data\aspnet-FEFA_MIS-20181011083349.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

Note: The project is developed in Asp.Net MVC using code first approach.

Comment: does reading the error help you in any way?

Comment: no, i need some suggestion here, I tried to delete the existing database but it created further issues @JohnB

Comment: what should i do? @JohnB

Comment: "...further issues..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: further issues means, it creates a new database and delete all user accounts and the previous data that exist in databse @JohnB

Comment: did you just copy the files over? it looks like a security issue of some sort either due to user account or change control.

Comment: yeah i copied the entire project and moved it to the new computer, anyhow what could be the possible solution? @ChrisBD